# nested resource not working testing view rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

i have some problem with nested resource in spec view rspec,

i have route like this :

```
resources :customers do
  resources :charges
end
```

and this my view testing using rspec :

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "charges/index", :type => :view do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:customers, [
      @customer1 = Customer.create!(
        :first_name => "tardjo",
        :last_name => "ea...ea...ea"
      ),
      @customer2 = Customer.create!(
        :first_name => "udin",
        :last_name => "penyok"
      )
    ])

    assign(:charges, [
      Charge.create!(
        :created => 1,
        :paid => false,
        :amount => 1.5,
        :currency => "Currency",
        :refunded => false,
        :disputed => false,
        :customer_id => @customer1.id
      ),
      Charge.create!(
        :created => 1,
        :paid => false,
        :amount => 1.5,
        :currency => "Currency",
        :refunded => false,
        :disputed => false,
        :customer_id => @customer2.id
      )
    ])
  end

  it "renders a list of charges" do
    render
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => 1.to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => false.to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => 1.5.to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Currency".to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => false.to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => 2.to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => false.to_s, :count => 2
  end
end
```

but i get error like this :

Failure/Error: render

ActionView::Template::Error:
   No route matches {:customer_id=>nil, :id=>1} missing required keys: [:customer_id]

stuck in here

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possibly a scoping problem

Try:

```
# these variables might need to be defined outside of the `:customers` array
@customer1 = Customer.create!(
    :first_name => "tardjo",
    :last_name => "ea...ea...ea"
)
@customer2 = Customer.create!(
    :first_name => "udin",
    :last_name => "penyok"
)
assign(:customers, [  @customer1, @customer2  ])
```